# Automating user input for C program

Tags: c, linux, automation

I am planing to make a C program using array of structures which takes input as strings i.e., name of movie and genre(4 different genres):

```
struct movie
   {
      char name[30];
      char genre[4][10];
   }m[30];

void main()
{
   int i,j;
   for(i=0;i<30;++i)
   {
      scanf("%s",m[i].name);                     //Removing gets
      for(j=0;j<4;++j)
      {
          scanf("%s",m[i].genre[j]);             //Removing gets
      }
   }
}
```

I want to automate the user input of the program from a pre-defined source e.g a text file, so that I don't have to insert all the input manually. Is there a script(python/bash) to do this or any other method that can make my job easier for 100s of input.

The reason behind using the C program is to store the inputs in a file for future use.

Comment: Never ever use `gets`. It is insecure.

Comment: Since your program is just reading from standard input, you can use the file redirection or pipeline features of the shell to feed it input.

Comment: On a Unix/Linux system, use input redirection, as in abelenky's answer.  (Dunno how easy/convenient this would be under Windows, though.)  While you're at it, create a test input file with name and genre strings longer than expected, and watch your program explode as the obsolete `gets` function fails to notice the overflow, and clobbers adjacent parts of memory.

Comment: @Ian, can you provide a reference for that? I'm curious to learn why it is insecure.

Comment: @glennjackman `gets` has no way to prevent buffer overrun. For that reason, it has been removed from C11.

Comment: @glennjackman Do a google search on "gets unsafe".  You'll get plenty of answers.

Comment: i am actually doing this on linux system, but the question is how should i arrange the data in input file so that for each iteration the expected input is used

Answer (score 7):

Write it to accept input from the keyboard. Then use input redirection:

```
myprogram.out < SampleTestData.txt
```

Uses the `SampleTestData.txt` file as if it were keyboard input.

Comment: i am using gcc on linux, so should my steps be like this :
    1st step: gcc myprogram.c                                                               
     2nd step: SampleTestData.txt > ./a.out

Comment: you might want to read on unix redirection:  
[link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-io-redirections.htm)
 
    `./a.out < SampleTestData.txt`